# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment / syntax-error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, logic

My code for a website of forum (blog) as followed :

```
import { AUTH } from '../actionTypes/actionTypes';
import * as api from '../api';

export default signin (formData, history) = async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.signIn(formData);

        dispatch({ type: AUTH, data });

        history.push('/');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

but I receive this error , line (4):

"ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

How to fix it?

Comment: What were you trying to do?

Comment: the "auth.js" in "actions" for signin and signup for my blog app

Comment: So you are trying to destruct an async response?

Comment: What are you trying to export? Either `export default (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {`…`};` or `export const signon = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {`…`};`. Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: I changed default by const , and added the "=" after signin and it worked !! thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I changed default by const , and added the "=" after signin and it worked !! thank you all